# How can I use a shell function with a return code in my git pre-commit hook using husky?

Tags: git, shell, sh, githooks, husky

I have a project with githooks managed by the [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) package. Usually I appreciate the fail-fast nature of the hooks (unsure if `set -e` is being used like in a shell script) but I ran into an issue today with my own custom function. I am trying to do one of two things depending on the return value of a function:

```
#!/bin/sh
my_func() {
  # some stuff
  return command
}

if my_func;
then
     echo "func returned 0"
else
     echo "func returned non-zero"
fi
```

The problem is as soon as any function returns a non-zero value husky quits out:

```
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

How can I ignore/handle non-zero returns from function calls? I don't think I want some type of global ignore as like I said I usually appreciate this fail-fast behavior for unhandled errors. Also I don't think I can switch away from function returns to a shared variable or something because I am doing a lot of async stuff with these function calls so I need their actual return values.

Comment: `return command` is not valid syntax: the `return` operation in shell takes either no parameter at all, or a small integer value to return (from 0 to 127; other values may or may not work correctly depending on shell vintage).

Comment: The syntax is fine (you'd get an error when trying to define the function if it weren't). `command` is just an invalid argument for `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not `if [ condition ]`.  It is `if cmd`.  (In the first case, the command is simply `[` with several arguments, the last of which is `]`).  All you need to do is:

```
if my_func; then
    echo myfunc returned 0
else
    echo myfunc returned non-zero
fi
```

Comment: My bad, I am reading the exit code slightly differently because of the async stuff I am doing. I have the same issue though. The script does not even get to the `if my_func;` check. It exits immediately after the return. I updated the question code assuming this is the correct syntax